# How to fix a memory leak in SBJsonParser implementation file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, memory-leaks, sbjson

While using Instruments ->Leaks in my app I have found that the largest memory leak is in SBJson Parser implementation file:

```
@implementation SBJsonStreamWriterAccumulator
@synthesize data;
- (id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:8096u]; //HERE IS 100% LEAK
}
return self;
}
#pragma mark SBJsonStreamWriterDelegate
- (void)writer:(SBJsonStreamWriter *)writer appendBytes:(const void *)bytes length:              (NSUInteger)length {
[data appendBytes:bytes length:length];
 }
 @end
```

1.How to fix this correctly and not to crash a parser?

2.And why are there so many troubles with memory leaks when working with SBJson ?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using SBJson 3.1 with a project that is not using ARC.
In ARC - this is just fine.
If your project is non arc, use SBJson 3.0, which is a non ARC version.

Comment: Or just toggle off the ARC build flag if you don't want to upgrade your version of SBJson.

Comment: -fno-objc-arc is the build flag to put on the .m file to prevent it from building in ARC.

Comment: @BillBurgess the problem is that his project is currently NOT using ARC (I assume) so disabling ARC will not help, because it's not there to begin with. He is using a library (in source format) that is designed for ARC. The previous version of SBJson is designed for non ARC projects and should solve his problem.

Comment: Ah, there is also a build flag to build the files for ARC when the project isn't I think. Not sure what the flag is though. You are right, just get the right version of the library for your project.

Answer (score -1):

1. Read the SBJson documentation https://github.com/stig/json-framework/blob/master/NEWS.md
2. Because people don't bother reading documentation.

There's an open bug to add a pragma to make the files NOT COMPILE unless ARC is used. I just haven't had time to fix it yet. See: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/issues/151

(Disclaimer: I am the SBJson author.)